# Trying to run a monte carlo of hydrus 1D

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run hydus 1D so that I can do a sensitivity analysis of the solute transport parameters. I've scripted a matlab code to generate the files for each MC run.  I can't get hydrus to run beyond the first path{i}.  I've been working through this with the matlab forum folks to no avail and now I'm thinking maybe it's something with hydrus? I believe I have all the input files needed for each iteration in each subfile, even including the .exe. but I can't get hydrus to execute in all the other path{i} .  Any help welcome.  Code below:

clear all;
clc;
%Solute transport parameters in row 47 of SELECTOR.IN file
SolTrans=[0.035 0 1 0.0479 0 0 0 0 273895 1 0 0 0 0]; %[Kd Nu Beta Henry SnkL1 SnkS1 SnkG1 SnkL1p SnkS1p SnkG1p SnkL10 SnkS10 SnkG10 Alfa] !! UPDATE NUMBERS IN BRACKETS !!

%~~~~~~
%ADD NOISE TO SOLUTE TRANSPORT PARAMETERS
num_sim=100;    %100 Monte Carlo Simulations
Kd=SolTrans(1)+.02*rand(1,num_sim); %a vector with 100 values of Kd parameters. We assume that the error is normally distributed with a standard deviation of ##.
Nu=SolTrans(2)+.02*rand(1,num_sim);
Beta=SolTrans(3)+.02*rand(1,num_sim);      %!!! CHANGE .02 FOR ALL THESE TO APPROPRIATE STANDARD DEVIATIONSN !!!
Henry=SolTrans(4)+.02*rand(1,num_sim);
SnkL1=SolTrans(5);
SnkS1=SolTrans(6);
SnkG1=SolTrans(7);
SnkL1p=SolTrans(8);
SnkS1p=SolTrans(9)+.02*rand(1,num_sim);      %!!! FOR AWI MODIFIED MODEL - KL - LANGMUIR EXPONENT FOR AWI FOR LANGMUIR SORPTION or 0 FOR FREUNDLICH SORPTION
SnkG1p=SolTrans(10);
SnkL10=SolTrans(11);
SnkS10=SolTrans(12);
SnkG10=SolTrans(13);
Alfa=SolTrans(14);

%~~~~~~
%INITIALIZE FILES AND DIRECTORIES

hydrus_exec='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Hydrus\Projects\ATSDR\AFFF1PFOS\H1D_CALC.exe';   %'C:\Program Files (x86)\PC-Progress\Hydrus-1D 4\H1D_calc.exe';
hydrus_ref='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Hydrus\Projects\ATSDR\AFFF1PFOS';
profileDAT='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Hydrus\Projects\ATSDR\AFFF1PFOS\PROFILE.DAT';
options='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Hydrus\Projects\ATSDR\AFFF1PFOS\OPTIONS.IN';
atmosph='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Hydrus\Projects\ATSDR\AFFF1PFOS\ATMOSPH.IN';
selectorIN='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Hydrus\Projects\ATSDR\AFFF1PFOS\SELECTOR.IN';
level='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Hydrus\Projects\ATSDR\AFFF1PFOS\LEVEL_01.dir';
work_dir='C:\Users\jessi\Desktop\Simulations';
mkdir(work_dir);

%~~~~~~
%CREATE DIRECTORIES AND INPUT FILES - This block is doing the work. Creates the input files for all realizations. Copies the mandatory file Profile.dat to
% the corresponding folder and creates the corresponding Selector
% .in. The Selector.in file is different for each realization since the solute transport parameters is
% variable. The code reads the reference Selector.in, copies the first 46 lines to the new file, write the van Genuchten parameters to the 47th line,
% and finally copies the last 10 lines from the reference Selector.in to the new file.

path=cell(1,num_sim);
for i=1:num_sim
path{i}=strcat(work_dir,'run_',num2str(i)); %create folder for each run
mkdir(path{i});

```
copyfile(profileDAT,path{i}); %copy profileDAt from reference directory to the simulation directory 
copyfile(options,path{i}); %copy options from reference directory to the simulation directory 
copyfile(atmosph,path{i}); %copy atmosph from reference directory to the simulation director
copyfile(hydrus_exec,path{i}); %copy options from reference directory to the simulation directory 

%create a new level_01.dir in each subdirectory with associated file
%directory path
fid_level = fopen(fullfile(path{i},'LEVEL_01.dir'),'w');
fprintf(fid_level,'%s',path{i});
fclose(fid_level);


fileID_out=fopen(strcat(path{i},'\selector.in'),'wt'); %manipulate Selector.in for each run
                    % "wt"= permision for file axis type
                    % w=Open or create new file for writing. Discard existing contents, if any.
                   % To open files in text mode, attach the letter 't' to the permission argument,
fileID_in=fopen(selectorIN);
skip_lines=46;      %!!! THIS IS THE LINE THAT CHANGES IN SELECTOR.IN FILE , i.e. solute transport parameters!!!
for k=1:(skip_lines)
    x=fgetl(fileID_in); %x = fgetl(fileID)= returns the next line of the specified file, removing the newline characters.
    fprintf(fileID_out,'%s\n',x);  % %s in the formatSpec input indicates that the values of the variables url and sitename, should be printed as text. 
                                   % '\n' as a newline indicator.   
                                   % "x" = prints the values from variable x
end

out_Sol=SolTrans; % Renaming...

%Whatever the solute transport parameter is for that monte carlo run (i)
out_Sol(1)=Kd(i);       % Solid phase sorption Kd
out_Sol(2)=Nu(i);       % Van Genuchten parameter
out_Sol(3)=Beta(i);     % Van Genuchten parameter
out_Sol(4)=Henry(i);     % Kh = KL*Rmax
out_Sol(9)=SnkS1p(i);    % KL - LANGMUIR EXPONENT FOR AWI FOR LANGMUIR SORPTION or 0 FOR FREUNDLICH SORPTION

fprintf(fileID_out,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n',out_Sol'); 
                         % %f = Fixed-point notation (Use a precision operator to specify the number of digits after the decimal point.)
                         % '\n' as a newline indicator. 
fgetl(fileID_in);        % returns the next line of the specified file, removing the newline characters.
skip_lines_end=5;       % CORRECT NUMBER???  DOUBLE CHECK
for k=1:(skip_lines_end)
    x=fgetl(fileID_in);
    fprintf(fileID_out,'%s\n',x);
end
fclose('all');
```

end

for i=1:num_sim
exec_path=['"' fullfile(path{i},'H1D_CALC.exe') '" "' path{i} '"'];
[x, y]= dos(exec_path);
if x % unsuccessful
error('exe failed'); % or take some other action besides throwing an error
end
end